# The right way of Drawing fonts in different colors in XNA/C#

Tags: c#, xna

Adding player name into list:

```
chatList0.Add(s);
```

Adding player msg into list:

```
chatList.Add(s);
```

Printing the player name & msg in different color:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < chatList0.Count(); i++)
            {
                //draw system msg (contains name/time/etc)
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, chatList0[i], new Vector2(40, arr1[i]), Color.Yellow);
                //check length of system msg
                Vector2 offset = textEntry.GetMeasurements(font, chatList0[i]);
                //draw msg after offset
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, chatList[i], new Vector2(offset.X + 40, arr1[i]), Color.White);
            }
```

Is this correct? Are there any changes needed to optimize the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DrawString` can only draw in one colour at a time, so you need to draw the 2 different bits of text separately.

I suggest making a class or struct for your messages, that has `PlayerName` and `Message` properties.

Then when you loop through each item to draw them, get the `PlayerName`, then use [`SpriteFont.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464128.aspx) to measure how wide the string will be.

Then draw the `PlayerName` (and a `": "` or whatever) where you currently do.

Then, draw the `Message`, in your other colour, offset by the `X` property of the vector returned from your measurestring method.

Comment: [upvode] @XNA newbie: your question is about algorithm you are using. you shall hold your player names and messages seperated. you need that's why an array to hold message positions (or do not use a second one use this : arr[i] + new Vector2(0, offset) )

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to call the DrawString method two times, one time for the name and one time for the message. Calculate the size if the name-string with MeasureString and write it on the screen. Draw the message right after the name-string based on the position of it, using the size of the name-string for the calculation of the position.